# How detect change title of single view page in webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a text view on my view so I want to change it based on the title of the web page. when the page loaded the first time I get the title from omPageFinished method of WebViewClient, but after that when the single view page change (for example loaded new page without reloading webview) how get the new title of the new page?

```kotlin
             override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                toolbar_title.text = view.title
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
 mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
                cardTitle.setText(title);
             }

    });
```